# Making sense of the term $H^1(N,A)^{G/N}$ in the inflation-restriction exact sequence.

Tags: group-cohomology

I am having troubles understanding the superscript "G/N" in the third term of the standard [inflation-restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation-restriction_exact_sequence) exact sequence
$$
0\to H^1(G/N,A^N)\to H^1(G,A)\to H^1(N,A)^{G/N}\to H^2(G/N,A^N)\to H^2(G,A)
$$

Is it assumed here that $G/N$ somehow acts on the first cohomology group
$H^1(N,A)$ so one could consider the fixed points of this action? If so, the action is quite nonobvious.

Comment: See Benson - Representations and Cohomology II section 3.5 for a description of how this action is defined.  Briefly, you take a $kG$-projective resolution of $k$ which is a $kN$-projective resolution by restriction, so can be used to calculate $H^1(N,A|_N)$.  Then the space of $N$-homs from this resolution to $A$ is a $G$-module ($(g\cdot f)(q)=gf(g^{-1}q)$), but $N$ acts trivially, hence it becomes a $G/N$-module.  This induces an action on the Ext-groups.